# Isolating add/remove class to clicked item

Tags: javascript, jquery, addclass, removeclass, toggleclass

Currently I have a accordion menu, each time `.responsive-accordion-head` is clicked I'm telling it to switch classes as follows:

```
$('.responsive-accordion-head').click(function () {

    if ( $( '.responsive-accordion-head i' ).hasClass( "plus-2" ) ) {

        $('.responsive-accordion-head i').removeClass("plus-2");
        $('.responsive-accordion-head i').addClass("minus-2");

    } else {
        $('.responsive-accordion-head i').removeClass("minus-2");
        $('.responsive-accordion-head i').addClass("plus-2");
    }

});
```

The problem I have is that the code above changes the classes for all `.responsive-accordion-head` elements. I need it to be specific to the clicked item only. How do I do this?

Comment: Inside the click callback, change all $( '.responsive-accordion-head i' ) to $(this).find('i')

Answer (score 5, accepted):

All that can probably be simplified to this:

```
$('.responsive-accordion-head').click(function () {
    $(this).find('i').toggleClass('plus-2 minus-2');
});
```

Comment: Well thats improved things two-fold. Brilliant thanks!